# grouping a date range by month in Crystal reports

Tags: date, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a SP in SQL that will pull data based on a start and end date. What I am trying to achieve in Crystal Reports is a way to group them by Month. most of the account only have 1 usage per month but now an again a few have more that one and I like to have crystal reports display them as a grouped total.

I think I need to make a formula that says is the date month is equal to 01 for Jan 02 for Feb, etc.

But I don't know how to write it.

any suggestions are very welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a group for month is fairly simple in Crystal Reports - a good tutorial for an older version can be found [here](http://www.lansa.com/support/tips/t0121.htm).

In simple steps:

1. Insert a group section onto your report.
2. Group on the date field
3. Select the dropdown for "this section will be printed:" and choose "for each month"

Comment: This solution might just work for you. However another option is grouping the results monthwise in the SP itself using PIVOT by summing all the data for a month. Personally, I think it will be a lot easier and manageable.